# How to add custom keyboard shortcut for terminal in apple macbook pro

Tags: macos, terminal

I don't think there is any pre-defined keyboard shortcut for opening terminal in macbook pro. I am about to start bash so really need to call up terminal fast. Can't use spotlight every time & then write `Terminal` their and call it. I just bought mac so i am getting familiar with all the custom keyboard shortcuts. I searched a lot on google but i couldn't find a way to add shortcut. I was using Linux Distro's before. Adding terminal shortcut is pretty easy in linux. In some distro's its predefined with ctrl+T key. Please let me know the easy way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drag Terminal from `Applications` to the `Dock` at the bottom of the screen and then you just click it whenever you want it

Comment: It's complicated but here's a link to help you http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [iterm2](http://iterm2.com/) or [total terminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/).

You can use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> to bring down a terminal whenever you need it.